# How does Adobe restrict .psd files for new versions of their software?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, metadata, psd

How does Adobe prevent users from opening a Photoshop CC .psd file to open with a previous Photoshop version like CS2 and is there a way to remove the restriction?

Comment: If they changed the file format (i.e. created a new version of it), it's not a restriction in the metadata, it's like an old english speaker trying to read modern english.

Answer (score 1):

As I explain in photo site check if this will work for you

Properties->File handling->Maximise PSD file compatibility->Always

(this should be executed in Photoshop)

And saving the file you will get maximum possible compatibility. Adobe write special flag, something like version of PSD file. And software check if this version is great than the version suported

Comment: I don't own a Photoshop CC copy - only CS2. I need to find a way to open a CC psd in CS2

Comment: Download CC trial, install it, open the file with it, save it with maximum compatibility and open it with CS2